# Why SvelteKit route slugs are indexed by the Google Search Console?

Tags: server-side-rendering, sveltekit, google-search-console

I have a full-stack SvelteKit application that uses SSR (no prerendering), and the Google Search Console indexes not only my resolved routes, but also the unresolved routes with slugs, like this:

[image: screenshot of Talers.io search console results]

How is it possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution or cause to this?

Comment: @TelFiRE I didn't do a thing but it seems fixed, I guess it's a SvelteKit bug that has been fixed. DO you also have this issue?

Comment: No I don't, was just reading up on Svelte and wanted to be prepared if I encountered it haha. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug has been fixed, I guess by an update of SvelteKit. Marking it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Two potential explanations

- You are running a static hosting website and these are folders on the file system. Directory listing is then exposed by your web server and Google indexes this.
- You are running some code to generate `sitemap.xml` or use a third party service for this. Then this code is buggy.

Comment: I am generating myself the sitemap and the routes are clean: https://talers.io/sitemap.xml

Solution #1 does not seem likely as well, as I don't host statically (I'm using SSR with node adapter and nowhere I am serving the directory structure). And I don't think the server proxy of my host is doing any static hosting.